# how to upload local video to aws s3 using boto3 flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I am new in flask.
I want to upload video in s3 aws using flask. Also, filename changes every time when a new file upload.
And there is subfolder in bucket like bucketname/videos I want to upload in videos

```
def uploadvideo():
finalResult = 'abc.mp4'
s3_bucket_video_url = 'media-storage-beta' + '/videos/' + 'video'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.upload_file(
    finalResult, 'media-storage-beta', 'video')
return 'success'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install boto3 in your virtualenv. Also depends where you are running Flask app. If you trying to upload from local. You need AWS access keys in the ENV variables. You can define a route like this in flask. A form with videotitle and upload file in form is used here.

```
@app.route('/uploadvideo', methods=['POST'])
def uploadvideo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form['videotitle'])
        f_video = request.files['videofile']
        print(f_video.filename)
        # create video_url
        s3_bucket_video_url = <Main_Folder> + '/videos/' + video_file_name
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3_client.upload_file(
            f.filename, <BUCKET_NAME>,s3_bucket_video_url)
        return 'Success'
```

Thanks

Ashish

Comment: should be f_video. Updated.

Comment: What error you get? in upload file function first value is path of video. last one is name. finalresult variable will have file name right? Not exactly path of the that video. In case that does not work you can try s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')

Comment: I am getting   this error ----->  raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string

Comment: finalresult is variable

Comment: Check type of finalResult. It seems its not string. You need to give path of converted or new written video. which will be the string.

Comment: now I convert to string but how to upload in subfolder

Comment: SO u successful uploaded see my code, s3_bucket_video_url no need to have bucket name. just give folder path